# MacOs software CRON-like

Tags: macos

I wrote scripts which permit to synchronise some of my local folders with a backup on a remote server (using ssh). In fact, these scripts permit to have an incremental save done.
In order to have a RPO less than 1 hour I have to play this script every hour.

Do you know an easy to use tool/software permitting to automate this (lauched at boot, running like a daemon) ?

thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On OS X `launchd` is handling all such things.

[Lingon](http://www.peterborgapps.com/lingon/) helps writing launchd plists.

Comment: the kind of tool I love to discover. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cron`, or the preferred [`launchd`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html)

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself: cron.  Cron runs happily in the terminal (Applications->Utilities->Terminal), and in Terminal you can do a "man cron" for details.

For what you want to do, it seems you just need a cron entry that looks like:

0 * * * * *synchronize-script-name.sh*

where *synchronize-script-name.sh* is the name of your script, and this will run it on the hour.

The crontab command lets you edit the crontab for any user (assuming you have su privilege, otherwise you can only edit your own)

Answer (score 0):

On startup? Or on login?
On login - [MacOSx launch application on system start](http://osxdaily.com/2006/11/29/how-to-launch-application-on-system-start-in-mac-os-x/)